# unmet dependencies when trying to install nvidia-docker

Tags: docker, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to install nvidia-docker on my azure virtual machine with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
```

I get this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-docker2 : Depends: docker-ce (>= 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not installable or
                           docker-ee (>= 18.06.0~ce~3-0~ubuntu) but it is not installable or
                           docker.io (>= 18.06.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

As I understand after some research, this is because I have an older docker version.

Trying to follow this instructions:
https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker/issues/857#issuecomment-439586831
But this gives me the following error:

```
E: Version '18.06.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu' for 'docker-ce' was not found
```

Next, I was trying to follow these instructions to uninstall old version of docker: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/
I then got the result:

```
Package 'docker-engine' is not installed, so not removed
```

sudo docker version gives the following output:

```
Client:
 Version:           3.0.11+azure
 API version:       1.40
 Go version:        go1.12.17
 Git commit:        eb310fca49568dccd87c6136f774ef6fff2a1b51
 Built:             Tue Mar  3 21:59:52 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          3.0.11+azure
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.17
  Git commit:       aa6a9891b0
  Built:            Tue Mar 10 18:53:36 2020
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.13
  GitCommit:        7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc10
  GitCommit:        dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Please help.